# Need to find top 3 employees

Tags: sql

I working with two tables

**Employee** ( empid integer, mgrid integer, deptid integer, salary integer)
**Dept** (deptid integer, deptname text)

I need to find top 3 employees (salary based), in every department. Result should have deptname, empid, salary sorted by deptname and then employee with high to low salary.

I appreciate all your help !!

Comment: what have u tried

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  A correct database tag, along with sample data and desired results benefit a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two parts in this query. The inner and outer query.

First part, I am partitioning at deptid level and assigning the rank to the salaries in the descending order which solves your problem.
Second part is just a select on all the output fields by filtering out only the top three employees in each department.

Key point :- Assigning rank to the salaries for each department using ROW_NUMBER window function in the inner query solves the entire problem.

```
SELECT deptname,empid,salary
  FROM
     (
        SELECT d.deptname,
               e.empid,
               e.salary,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY e.deptid ORDER BY 
               e.salary DESC ) AS rank_salary_by_dept
          FROM dept d, employee e
         WHERE d.deptid = e.deptid
      )
WHERE rank_salary_by_dept <= 3
ORDER BY deptname,rank_salary_by_dept;
```

Comment: Thanks SOaddict. Is it possible for you to explain what the script in quotes doing ? OVER ( PARTITION BY e.deptid ORDER BY e.salary DESC ). I get the ORDER BY, but referring to "OVER: and "PARTITION BY"

Comment: I answered your question with more details.

Comment: Let me know if you still have any questions.

Comment: Yes, I have one more. How can I list all employees, their salary and the salary of the person in their department who makes the most money, but less than the employee form the same 2 tables. Thanks.

Comment: there is a up arrow above green tick